# I need advice for 'Foreach loop' task

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $a=array (
        16=> 'Ivan',
        18=> 'Mitko',
        21=>'Pesho',
        14=> 'Misho'
        );
        foreach($a as $k=>$v){
        if ( $k>=18 ){
            echo $k. '--' .$v.'<br>';
            }
        }
?>
```

So everything works good but i want to display and the 'keys' who are under 18 and i want to display how much they need to reach 18.

For example:

18--Mitko
21--Pesho

16--Ivan +2
14--Misho +4

Should i use 'else'?

I hope your understood me.

Comment: Use an elseif($k<=18){//your code here}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $a=array (
        16=> 'Ivan',
        18=> 'Mitko',
        21=>'Pesho',
        14=> 'Misho'
        );
        foreach($a as $k=>$v){
            if ( $k>=18 ){
                echo $k. '--' .$v.'<br>';
            }
            else{
                $toreach = 18-$k;
                echo $k.'--'.$v.' +'.$toreach;
            }
        }
?>
```

Like this ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

  $a = array (
    16=> 'Ivan',
    18=> 'Mitko',
    21=>'Pesho',
    14=> 'Misho'
    );

    foreach($a as $k=>$v){
        if ( $k >= 18 )
            echo $k . '--' . $v . '<br />';
        elseif ($k < 18)
            echo $k . '--' . $v . ' +' . (18-$k) . '<br />';
    }

?>
```

If you want to seperate the key's under 18 and above use this code:

```
<?php

  $a = array (
    16=> 'Ivan',
    18=> 'Mitko',
    21=>'Pesho',
    14=> 'Misho'
    );

    foreach($a as $k=>$v){
        if ( $k >= 18 )
            echo $k . '--' . $v . '<br />';

    }

    foreach($a as $k=>$v){
        if ($k < 18)
            echo $k . '--' . $v . ' +' . (18-$k) . '<br />';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to else{ }

```
else{
 $getK = 18 - $k;
 echo $k. '--' .$v.' + '.$getK.'<br>';
  }
```